# Integrating Google +1 button "offline" and without tracking

Tags: performance, social-networking, privacy

the official way to include a Google +1 button is to add some javascript hosted on Google's server which draws the button.

For a couple of reasons I don't want this on my site:

- Privacy: Social network providers know their users visisted my site even if they don't click on the button.
- Performance: Additionnal requests to social network sites needed to load the page.
- Security: Who knows how this javascript could interfere with my site when it's changed.

So I would like to host a +1 image linking to some url like it is possible with Facebook for exmaple http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://my.site.com

I have no need for showing the number of +1s on my site.

Any official or unofficial solutions for this available?

Comment: You may try asking on the webapps stackexchange, it have [something similar](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17027/).

Comment: I'm using jquery/cluetip popups and iframes for exactly the reasons you mentioned. http://use-the-index-luke.com/ on the right hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an article at slashdot about Heise news (big german IT news site) introducing a "2-click" system for social sites like facebooke, twitter and Google+.

http://yro.slashdot.org/story/11/09/03/0115241/Heises-Two-Clicks-For-More-Privacy-vs-Facebook

If you look at http://heise.de itself, you'll see their grayed icon's and "slider" approach.

Seems like they replace the elements when you click.

Interesting is also the reaction of facebook, read the article ;)